# Install Old Solc Compiler Versions

Tags: contract-debugging, solc, solcjs

I would like to compile older versions of solc contract source code using a solc compiler on my local machine. Is there a website from which to download old solc compilers?

Google revealed a [GitHub of old solcs](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin), but I tried using node to run the `.js`. files without success (could be using this wrong).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I maintain a Python library called [py-solc-x](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/py-solc-x) that allows you to install and use multiple versions of solc at the same time.  It supports versions `>=0.4.11`. I've included some code examples below to give an idea of how it works.

#### Installing a new version of solc:

```py
>>> from solcx import install_solc
>>> install_solc('v0.4.25')
```

#### Checking installed versions and versions can be installed:

```py
>>> from solcx import get_installed_solc_versions, get_available_solc_versions
>>> get_installed_solc_versions()
['v0.4.25', 'v0.5.3', 'v0.6.0']
>>> get_available_solc_versions()
['v0.6.0', 'v0.5.15', 'v0.5.14', 'v0.5.13', 'v0.5.12', 'v0.5.11', 'v0.5.10', 'v0.5.9', 'v0.5.8', 'v0.5.7', 'v0.5.6', 'v0.5.5', 'v0.5.4', 'v0.5.3', 'v0.5.2', 'v0.5.1', 'v0.5.0', 'v0.4.25', 'v0.4.24', 'v0.4.23', 'v0.4.22', 'v0.4.21', 'v0.4.20', 'v0.4.19', 'v0.4.18', 'v0.4.17', 'v0.4.16', 'v0.4.15', 'v0.4.14', 'v0.4.13', 'v0.4.12', 'v0.4.11']
```

#### Setting the current solc version using a pragma statement:

```py
>>> set_solc_version_pragma('^0.4.20 || >0.5.5 <0.7.0', check_new=True)
Using solc version 0.5.8
Newer compatible solc version exists: 0.6.0
```

Comment: Super cool product, but I am running Ubuntu, which is not supported by this tool. Thank you for sharing this with me.

Comment: It's tested against and working on Ubuntu 18.04 :)

Comment: Wow, okay, this is really great. I must have entered something incorrectly beforehand. Thank you!

Comment: For clarification: originally I visited the `py-solc` package instead of the `py-solc-x` package. The latter is superior, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this and the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/installing-solidity.html) has a page on it:

Keep in mind you have the option to use the "cli binary" version (solc-bin) which is quite faster than the solcjs ( javascript implementation ).

In addition to all of these, if you use truffle, you can specify which version you would like to use with it in your truffle-config.js file.

```js
  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.10" // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {
      //   // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //   optimizer: {
      //     enabled: true,
      //     runs: 200
      //   }
      //   //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will probably end up using Truffle, but visiting the https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases?after=v0.4.26 I found in the solidity documentation gave me the binaries I needed.