# How to remove solc from Ubuntu (WSL)

Tags: solidity

I apply all commands (i.e.  `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove solc`)  to remove solc from my Ubuntu bash (WSL)... but after removing, when i type solc --version (it print version 0.4.24) and when i type solcjs --version it print 0.5.14... I just want to remove all my solc or just upgrade it to new version... is there any solution.. i searched a lot and couldn't found any solution to upgrade or remove solc...

Comment: if you type `which solc` you can find and delete the binary yourself

Comment: thanks , is there any other auto way , especially for upgrade solc or remove solc

Comment: and if i want to install specific version of solc.. (i.e. 0.5.10) then how could i install , then

Comment: This might be useful - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78448/install-old-solc-compiler-versions/78460#78460

Answer (score 0):

If you installed over snap, use this command

> snap remove solc