# having a problem with solc-x version "solc 0.6.0 has not been installed"

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, python, solc, py-solc-x

I m trying to print out the variable (`compiled_sol`) as you will see in the code below of the python file named `deploy.py` so I can deploy my smart contract, but I keep running at this error

```
*****INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\houde\Desktop\Blockchain\solidity_projects\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 8, in <module> 
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\Users\houde\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 368, in compile_standard 
    solc_binary = get_executable(solc_version)
  File "C:\Users\houde\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 194, in get_executable
    raise SolcNotInstalled(
solcx.exceptions.SolcNotInstalled: solc 0.6.0 has not been installed. Use solcx.install_solc('0.6.0') to install. ******
```

I did install the `solc-x` via this command *`pip install py-solc-x`* so I can compile the contracts but I don't know how to upgrade the version or what to do in this case, I will leave the code for you guys down below, and thank you a lot.

```
from solcx import compile_standard

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "solidity",
        "sources": {"simpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

print("compiled_sol")
```

note:"the solc version 0.6.0 I m using it for the contract"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm working through this same course check this out and it will show you how to fix this error here: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/blob/main/chronological-issues-from-video.md

You just need to do the following:
On the line that says

```py
from solcx import compile_standard
```

We need to change it to this line:

```py
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
```

And then, we need to add a line right before we run the `compile_standard` code:

```py
install_solc("0.6.0")
```

Alternatively, you can [install Solc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/installing-solidity.html) first before installing solcx and it will give you the old version of solidity compiler included. so all you have to do is import from solcx.

Also I noticed in your settings array here:

```
"*": {"*": {"abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"}}
```

you used curly braces instead of square brackets so you will need to fix that before you try to compile. It needs to look like this

```
"*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping, yes indeed for the arrays I didn't really pay attention until the JSON error popped up, I wish you good luck on the journey

Answer (score 4):

you did not import install_solc. Do it, and install the version you want

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

install_solc("0.6.0")
```

i would recommend using a framework like brownie to avoid such problems. You dont really need to do everything by yourself if you have brownie.
https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:
[Install Old Solc Compiler Versions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78448/install-old-solc-compiler-versions/78460#78460)

You just need to import the function you're going to call

Answer (score 1):

The error you get says:

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\houde\Desktop\Blockchain\solidity_projects\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 8, in compiled_sol = compile_standard( File "C:\Users\houde\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 368, in compile_standard solc_binary = get_executable(solc_version) File "C:\Users\houde\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 194, in get_executable raise SolcNotInstalled( solcx.exceptions.SolcNotInstalled: solc 0.6.0 has not been installed. **Use solcx.install_solc('0.6.0') to install**.

The last line is telling you what to do. Therefore use this code:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc # <- import the install_solc method!
install_solc('0.6.0') # <- Add this line and run it at least once!

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "solidity",
        "sources": {"simpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

print("compiled_sol")
```

Answer (score 0):

3:43:52 Installing solcx version 0.6.0

In the video, we forgot to do 2 things in order to compile our solidity code:

Import install_solc, so we need to change this line:

from solcx import compile_standard

To this line:

from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

And then, we need to add a line right before we run the compile_standard code:

(in terminal)
install_solc("0.6.0")

Answer (score 0):

I too am following same course and kept having same error even after following all the recommended steps above so far.
finally resolve it by doing

> npm install -g solc

now it's all up to you whether to install solc globally or not